# Duplicating a section but with different texts, titles and images

Tags: html, hugo, blogdown

I'm making a website using this hugo theme: https://themes.gohugo.io/theme/vex-hugo/
I'm planning to make two sections of "Our Core Features" with different title, text and images. However I can't seem to make them independent from one another. They always have the same title, text and images whenever i make changes in only one of the sections.
[image: Picture of one section]
Here is the HTML code for this section.

```
{{- if .Site.Data.homepage.features.enable }}
{{- with .Site.Data.homepage.features }}
<section class="section" id="feature">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="heading">
          <h2>{{ .title | markdownify }}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ range .leftSide }}
        <div class="mb-40 text-center text-md-left">
          <i class="d-inlin-block h2 mb-10 {{ .icon }}"></i>
          <h4 class="font-weight-bold mb-2">{{ .title | markdownify }}</h4>
          <p>{{ .content | markdownify }}</p>
        </div>
        {{ end }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center align-self-center mb-4 mb-md-0">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ .image | absURL }}" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
          {{ range .rightSide }}
        <div class="mb-40 text-center text-md-left">
          <i class="d-inlin-block h2 mb-10 {{ .icon }}"></i>
          <h4 class="font-weight-bold mb-2">{{ .title | markdownify }}</h4>
          <p>{{ .content | markdownify }}</p>
        </div>
        {{ end }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- .container close -->
</section>
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

What should I do?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you configuring the second set of feature data? How did you change the template with your second features section?

Comment: nevermind I got it. i had to change the name of the input variable. since the names of the variables were identical, i couldn't keep the sections independent. thanks though!